# Shift the values in a record by a column.

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

I have a dataframe, where one of the observations has mismatched columns. Kind of like this :

```
  Names    Age   Dept
0  John     21  sales
1   Joe     22     IT
2   Ann     20     IT
3    24  sales    NaN
```

I want to shift the values, to the next column and assign NaN on the first column which actually has the missing value.

```
   Names  Age   Dept
0  John   21  sales
1   Joe   22     IT
2   Ann   20     IT
3   NaN   24  sales
```

I searched a lot, but did not find a method to do this. I feel there should be an inbuilt method to do it in a simple way.

I am a newbie to programming, so sorry if it is a basic question.

Answer (score 1):

Create boolean mask by [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) with [`notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.notna.html) or function [`isnumeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.isnumeric.html) for find problematic rows and then [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) only filtered rows:

```
m = pd.to_numeric(df['Names'], errors='coerce').notna()
#alternative
#m = df['Names'].str.isnumeric()

df[m] = df[m].shift(axis=1)
print (df)
  Names Age   Dept
0  John  21  sales
1   Joe  22     IT
2   Ann  20     IT
3   NaN  24  sales
```

Answer (score 1):

Or use a `df[...]=df[...]` structure:

```
df[df['Dept'].isnull()]=df[df['Dept'].isnull()].shift(axis=1)
```

And now:

```
print(df)
```

Is:

```
  Names Age   Dept
0  John  21  sales
1   Joe  22     IT
2   Ann  20     IT
3   NaN  24  sales
```

`shift(axis=1)` is shifting row by row, and if you remove `axis=1` part, `shift()` it will shift column by column.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Thanks, happy it's alright, :-), :D

Comment: could you please confirm once if `shift(axis=1)` is shifting 1st and last column with each other, will be grateful to you if you could explain this one.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Sorry for lateness of reply, sure, i can do that.